# intersect stacked images R

Tags: r, list, stack, raster, intersect

I downloaded 50 **landsat 8** images and extracted them in a subfolder Landsat8

By iterating through the list of folders containing the images I extracted 2 bands to calculate a vegetation index (LSWI) with a function created and called **calcIndex**:

```
for(scene in folders){
 NIR <- raster(b5.tif)
 SWIR1 <- raster(b6.tif)

 LSWI <- overlay(x=nir, y=SWIR1, fun=calcIndex)
 writeraster(LSWI, filename=LSWIxxx.tif, format='GTiff', datatype = 'FLT4s')
}
```

This all works, I can access all the LSWI.tiff files and import them in ArcGIS for example. My problem is related to stacking (or brick) them and using the stacked file for analysis.

I selected all the LSWI.tif files in a list and stacked that list:

```
LSWI_list <- list.files(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "LSWI.tif$") 
LSWI_stack <- stack(LSWI_list, quick = TRUE)
```

I used quick = TRUE here to assure the stacking works despite different extents of the images. Now I want to use intersect to find the largest common area of all the images and crop all images on the resulting extent, **can somebody explain to me how to use the intersect function on a large stacked list of images?** I want to for example sum all the images up, which I think only works if all the extents are equal.

On top of that I would like to access one particulair location (coordinate system WGS84, units in meters is assigned automatically) and derive **all** LSWI values form the images of that particular location.

Hopefully I made my challenges clear. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the largest extent I think the best options would be to either draw a polygon/shapefile around the area of interest and crop the images pre-stacking. Or alternatively count the number of non-na cells which should show where most observations fall, in your case the following should work:

```
rNA <- sum(!is.na(LSWI_stack))
```

To access an individual point location, you need to first make a spatial object out of the co-ordinate(s), reproject this to the Landsat CRS, and use raster::extract() to get the values. This blog post covers most of this in good details
https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/spatialdataintro/